# How to access a class in a javascript module from type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript

I want to use the following code in an HTML document:

```html
<html>
<script type="module">
   import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js';                 
    alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
</script>

<script type="text/">
    alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
</script>
</html>
```

The first `alert` works fine, but the second one in `type="text/javascript"` does not because it is out of scope. How can I call the `Dms` class from the second script?

I also tried

```html
<script type="module">
   import  Dms  from './geodesy/dms.js';             
   alert (Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
   window.dms = Dms;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   alert (dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
</script>
```

After all I use

```
    <script>

  (async () => {
    
    const {default: Dms} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js');
    alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
  
  })();

</script>
```

But now I have the next problem: how to use a second module?
I want to use

```
import Mgrs, { LatLon } from 'geodesy/mgrs.js';
```

(see https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy)

How must the const declaration must look for it?

I'm not firm with this.

Comment: Don't use the `type` attribute for anything other than "module", or when you explicitly want to make the `<script>` block be ignored (with some random not-real type).

Comment: Also you will be running into the problem that module scripts are implicitly deferred, while your plain script is not. Thus when your plain script runs, even if you do the explicit `window.dms` export, the symbol will be missing because the module script won't have finished yet. You can (probably) make the plain script a module also, which *might* work.

Comment: Why do you need a second script? Just put all the code in a single module script.

Comment: Thank you. But if I not type="text/javascript" or use only one type="module"-Block the other code being in <script type="text/javascript"> will not run. For example body onload="initialize()"> results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined"

Comment: Yes. Use `document.body.onload = initialize;` from inside the module scope instead.

Comment: unfortunately this did not help. I try something but no effort. I create a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kaenLfr/1/

Answer (score 1):

A `window` property setter solution:

```html
<script type="module">
   import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js';                 
   alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
   window.Dms = Dms;
</script>

<script>
  let Dms;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'Dms', {
    get(){
      return Dms;
    },
    set(val){
      Dms = val;
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('dms-set'));
    }
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('dms-set', () => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));
  
</script>
```

Some promise solution:

```html
<script type="module">
   import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js';                 
   alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
   window.Dms = Dms;
</script>

<script>

  promisifyGlobal('Dms');
  
  Dms.then(Dms => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));

  function promisifyGlobal(name){
    let global, promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, name, {
        get(){
          return promise;
        },
        set(val){
          global = val;
          resolve(global);
        }
      });
    });
  }

</script>
```

You can easily import dynamically into a non-module script:

```html
<script>

  (async () => {
    
    const {default: Dms} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js');
    alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
  
  })();

</script>
```

And finally some crazy generic solution:

```html
<script type="module">

  import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js'; 
  alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));

</script>

<script>

  // this script will handle all imports 
  // tweak to import several exports and named exports

  for(const script of document.querySelectorAll('script[type=module]')) {
    
    const regex = /import\s+([^\s]+)\s+from\s+["\']([^"\']+)/g;
    let matches;
    while(matches = regex.exec(script.textContent)){
      const [, name, url] = matches;
      const src = `import ${name} from '${url}'; export default ${name};`;
      window[name] = new Promise(resolve => {
        import(`data:text/javascript, ${src}`).then(({default:imported}) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(imported));
        });
      });
    }

  }

</script>

<script>

  Dms.then(Dms => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));

</script>
```

Comment: It's really confusing to have `Dms` and `window.Dms` do different things. Why not simply fire the event from the module?

Comment: @Bergi i guess it's rather an experiment. also the workflow could be generalized like i did in the second promise solution

Comment: @Bergi added in the end a more generic solution. it's all pure experimental

Comment: The async-solution work. https://jsfiddle.net/wtc1089u/
But I'm wondering: why I'm the only person with this problem?

Comment: @Krubkjlkjlökg if the async solution works for you you could accept my answer (the checkbox) and upvote it (the arrow up). that way i'll get points and will be motivated to help you in the future